# How to replace value in Json by a CSV in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

Now I'm working with Apache Nifi, need to use value from a CSV file and write it in to a JSON.
I have a JSON like that:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "key_name1",
    "name": "key_name1"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name2",
    "name": "key_name2"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name3",
    "name": "key_name3"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name4",
    "name": "key_name4"
  }
]
```

and a CSV:

```js
Key            Value
key_name1      key_value1
key_name2      key_value2
key_name3      key_value3
key_name4      key_value4
```

Output JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "key_name1",
    "name": "key_value1"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name2",
    "name": "key_value2"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name3",
    "name": "key_value4"
  },
  {
    "key": "key_name4",
    "name": "key_value4"
  }
]
```

How can i do that. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like LookupRecord should work for this, you can match the `key` field and look up the `Value` field to fill in the `name` value in the record.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I used LookupRecord with CSV-File. It worked!!